# Query DynamoDB for highest sort key from C#

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I have a `DynamoDB` table with two keys that numbers, lets call them `key1` (partition key)  and `key2` (sort key) for arguments sake now.

I want to query the table for the row where `key1 = some_val` and the highest `key2`.  I'm writing this application in C#.

I've found a lot of examples where I can query where I have both keys, or the second one is using some value (i.e. `key2 > some_other_val`) but none where I can just grab the highest one.  If possible I'd like to not load the partition and sort myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query by specifying only the partition key, and using reverse order (set the `ScanIndexForward` parameter for the query to `false`) with limit 1 (set the `Limit` parameter to `1`). When making a query request only the partition (or hash) key value is required. The sort (or range) is optional.

This way, the first item returned will be the item that has the "highest" value for the sort key.

See the [documentation for Queries and Scans](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#ScanQueryLimit)